# Find matching point epipolar geometry

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I'm trying to determine the position of an object, seen on two images at the same time, in python. I already found the fundamental matrix of the situation thanks to openc and now, what I'm trying to do, is chosing a point in an image and finding the matching point on the second image with the help of the fundamental matrix, but I don't find anything on internet, or in the opencv library.

Does anyone have a solution ?

Comment: could you add a sample code that explains what you mean by matching points and fundamental matrix?

Comment: If you are not familiar with the notion of epipolar geometry and the opencv python module, I'm afraid you won't be able to help me out...

Comment: I agree with the sentiment, Mehdi's web development and NLP won't help here at all, but you seem confused about the math and practice of stereo vision as well. these matrices give you a relation between one point in one image and *an entire line* in the other image. it is a mathematical fact that you have to deal with in stereo vision. it is usually dealt with by finding correspondences by correlation (block matching), checking along that line.

Comment: Perhaps I can remove the comment if it is offensive? :)

Comment: I have limited experience with stereo cameras, but I suspect your question is answered in the tutorial: https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/da/de9/tutorial_py_epipolar_geometry.html

The idea is that, with `F` fundamental of two images, any point from image2 (`pts2`) could be matched with any point on their corresponding epilines on image1 (`lines1`):
`lines1 = cv.computeCorrespondEpilines(pts2.reshape(-1,1,2), 2, F)` (check last block f code)
`pts1` and `pts2` happen to be the matched points that were used for calculating `F`, therefore they are on on the epilines.

Comment: Thanks Christoph, can you develop your point please ? I don't know what to look up for now

Answer (score 0):

Based on the [tutorial here](https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/da/de9/tutorial_py_epipolar_geometry.html), first, we need a bunch of matching points to extract the fundamental matrix.
So, to show how it works, I created a synthetic set of matching points to extract the fundamental matrix. Then, I show you how one can use the fundamental matrix to extract the epilines in the second image, for any given point in the first image. If the point from the first image represents an object, the object is located somewhere on the epiline in the second image.

So, I start with two synthetic empty images in RGBA, a set of arbitrary points in the first image, and an arbitrary transformation function `transform_fn` to map points on the first image onto the second image:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2 as cv

img1 = np.ones((64, 64, 4), dtype=np.uint8) * 255
img2 = np.ones_like(img1, dtype=np.uint8) * 255

pts1 = [
    [10, 20],
    [25, 20],
    [28, 18],
    [30, 15],
    [50, 40],
    [53, 43],
    [55, 45],
    [18, 58],
]
transform_fn = lambda pt: [
    int(pt[0]*.5)+int(pt[1]*.2) + 5, 
    int(pt[0]*.2)-int(pt[1]*.4) + 25,
]

pts2 = [transform_fn(pt) for pt in pts1]

# paint black
for (i, j) in pts1:
    img1[i, j, :-1] = 0 

# paint black
for (i, j) in pts2:
    img2[i, j, :-1] = 0 
    
pts1 = np.int32(pts1)
pts2 = np.int32(pts2)
```

With these paired points (`pts1` and `pts2`), we can the extract fundamental matrix:

```
F, _ = cv.findFundamentalMat(pts1, pts2, cv.FM_LMEDS)
```

`F` above is the fundamental matrix. Before showing how F works, I need an arbitrary point in the first image that is synthetically mapped to a point in the second image as the gold standard for evaluation and demo.

I chose `pt1 = [32, 32]` to demonstrate this. Using `transform_fn`, the location of this point in second image must be `pt2 = transform_fn(pt1)`. I paint them red, and plot the images:

```
pt1 = [32, 32]
pt2 = transform_fn(pt1)

# paint red
img1[pt1[0], pt1[1], :] = np.array([255, 0, 0, 255])
img2[pt2[0], pt2[1], :] = np.array([255, 0, 0, 255])


from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

def plot(img1, img2): 
    fig, axs = plt.subplots(1, 2, )

    axs[0].imshow(img1)
    axs[0].set_xticks([])
    axs[0].set_yticks([])
    axs[0].set_xlabel('img1')

    axs[1].imshow(img2)
    axs[1].set_xticks([])
    axs[1].set_yticks([])
    axs[1].set_xlabel('img2')

    plt.show()
```

[image: synthetic image with points before drawing the epiline]

```
plot(img1, img2)
```

Now, all we need to do is to use `F` to find the epiline corresponding to point `pt1`. We expect `pt2` to be on the epiline. Here is the demostration:

```
lines2 = cv.computeCorrespondEpilines(np.array([pt1]), 1, F)
lines2 = lines2.reshape(-1,3)
lines2

_, c, _ = img1.shape
for r in lines2:
    j0, i0 = map(int, [0, -r[2]/r[1] ])
    j1, i1 = map(int, [c, -(r[2]+r[0]*c)/r[1] ])
    
    img2 = cv.line(img2, (i0, j0), (i1, j1), [255, 255, 0, 127], 1) # yello line
    img2[pt2[0], pt2[1], :] = np.array([255, 0, 0, 255]) # red-dot (true location)

plot(img1, img2)
```

[image: synthetic image with points after drawing the epiline]

Comment: I am at this step of the tutorial, but I now want to find the exact matching point and not the line. I have a problem : when I draw the epiline on the image 2, it is perfect, but when I try to find the point where x1.T @ F @ x2, it is a total disaster